# How to modify this schematic for more amps?

Tags: power-supply, schematics

How can this schematic be altered for more amps and to match my transformer? The transformer I am using outputs 21-0-21 volts ,4amps.

[image: split supply]

Comment: Perhaps you should at least annotate the schematic for a non-Russian speakers...

Answer (score 2):

It will work with the values and ratings shown, however the output current will be limited **by the regulators** to (at most) 1.5A or by the thermal limit set by the heatsinks, power dissipation and ambient temperature.

If you want to use the full ~2.5A capability of the transformer you'll need significant modifications to the regulators- something like the [LT1085](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1185ff.pdf)/[LT1185](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1185ff.pdf) rather than the LM317/LM337. The former are LDO regulators so the output capacitors shown may result in oscillation unless some series resistance is added, and there may be other differences. See the relevant data sheets which I have linked. The heat sinking may still be limiting. To output (say) 0.1V at 2.5A means your power dissipation could be in the 70W range per regulator, which is enough to fry eggs (and silicon chips) if not properly disposed of (perhaps with a hefty heat sink and a fan).

Along with the regulators, the input filter capacitors will need to be increased in capacitance and the bridge rectifier beefed up (as Brian mentions below) to get significantly more current than shown. The ripple current rating on the input filter capacitors must also be considered. There are nice 35A packaged bridges with spade terminals that will do this job easily and can be bolted down the heatsink (cost is quite reasonable). Anyway, at that point you're essentially designing from scratch something to perform a similar function, so every single part should be considered as well as the data sheet recommendations for the higher-current regulators.

Comment: Even at 1.5A, those 1A diodes (VD1 to VD4) will be a problem, the others are probably OK. 1N5401 etc rated for 3A would be an option.

Comment: @BrianDrummond They're probably okay since 1A diodes make a 2A bridge rectifier, but 1N5404 etc. would certainly be better. For the 2.5A version they must be changed.